# Why <h1> in <header>?

Tags: html, header

I just finished the Code School's [Functional HTML5 & CSS3](http://www.codeschool.com/courses/functional-html5-css3) and I noticed several times they emphasized that the `<header>` element should contain `<h1>` heading (not `<h2>`, `<h3>` etc.) but they did not explain why.

Why is that? What makes the `<h1>` so special that it is the one that we should include in `<header>`?

Comment: `<h1>` is not special - [This article](http://html5doctor.com/the-header-element/) may help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the `header` of the page is like the header of a document, you'll usually find the main title of the document there. The main title of a webpage is usually put into an h1, but headers can contain lots of other things like a logo, publication date and other metadata. On many websites, the sit's header also contains its navigation.

Answer (score 2):

`h1` is the primary (ie: the most important) header.

The `header` tag is not limited to only containing the `h1`, but as it is the most important header on the page, that may often be the case.